# Two Tomcat web applications killing one another's Rest interface

Tags: tomcat, java

I have a java web app running on a tomcat server with some Rest interfaces that have run without fail for months.  Now we put another war in their and it has stopped the rest interfaces completely.  The rest of the app runs and can talk to the database, but we get 503 errors when we look for the interfaces.  The only thing of note, is the new war immediately throws an exception and fails because of a missing dependency.

What should I be looking for, for the cause of this?

Comment: A 503 error means that you should have an error logged.  Check the logs.

Comment: @Shane Madden I know, catalina and the applications logs are devoid of anything related.
Im thinking its a configuration issue, but my googling skills are failing, and im finding nothing in the configs i can find.

Comment: Post your configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was fixed by adding the below to apache's proxy_ajp.conf.
proxy_ajp.conf, however, did have an entry for the working app, so i am still unsure why that would break.

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(new_app.*)$    balancer://tomcat_base_dir/$1  stickysession=JSESSIONID timeout=1800
```